# ImageMagick still broken (using with /usr/bin/convert)

Tags: imagemagick

Despite trying all the fixes on this board and elsewhere, I *STILL* get the same break running

```
$ /usr/bin/convert D1.JPG P1.pdf
```

namely:

```
unable to open image `P1.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: missing an image filename `20' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3255.
```

This bug started in U18.04 initial release and still persists on latest U18.04 refresh - it has never been fixed.

Comment: Interesting. I get a different error message when trying to convert jpg to pdf. `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.` (I am on 19.04)

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick has **blocked** that for security reasons. You edit the policy though. Read more [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php)

Follow these steps to edit

```
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Then change

```
<!-- From -->
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />

<!-- To -->
<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />
```

Now run the command again: `/usr/bin/convert D1.JPG P1.pdf`